# Derivative of a summation.

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

If a function $E={1\over2}\sum_{n=1}^N(y_k-t_k)^2$
And if $a_k = y_k$ then how

${\partial E \over {\partial a_k}} =y_k - t_k$

Can anyone please tell me how final answer was obtained using partial derivative.

Thanks

Comment: You mean $n$ where you wrote $k$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E(y_1,...,y_N)=\frac 1 2\sum_{n=1}^N(y_n-t_k)^2=\frac 1  2((y_1-t_1)^2+(y_2-t_2)^2+\cdots+(y_N-t_N)^2)$$

Note that all the terms but the $i$-th don't depend on $y_i$, so their derivative is $0$, now

$$
\frac {\partial E}{\partial y_i}=\frac \partial {\partial y_i}\left(\frac 1 2 (y_i-t_i)^2\right)
$$

And use the chain rule.